# Efficient array reshaping and tile operations

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I would like to make the following set of operations in a more efficient way:

```
import numpy as np
from time import time

n1  = 5
n2  = 800
n3  = 1000  

a    = np.random.rand( n1,n2,n3 )

ts = time()

a_new  = np.array( [ np.repeat( a[np.newaxis,ll,:,:], n1, axis=0  ) for ll in range(n1)] )

print(time()-ts)
ts = time()
d      = n1**2
a_new  = np.reshape( a_new, ( d, n2, n3  ) )    
a_new  = np.repeat( a_new[np.newaxis,:,:,:], n1, axis=0 )

print(time()-ts)
ts = time()
d2     = d*n1      
a_new  = np.reshape( a_new, ( d2, n2, n3 ))
a_new  = np.reshape( a_new, ( d2*n2 , n3 ) )

print(time()-ts)
```

When n1,n2,n3 are becoming quite large, this becomes kind of inefficient. What is the best way to proceed?

Comment: Please explain in text the following set of operations.

Comment: Perhaps the "operations" part is a bit misleading; I just want the same transformation as in the minimal example, but to do this in a more efficient way. It all roots down to replicating the input array a total of n1**2 times, but with the order I follow in the example.

Comment: what's taking the most time?

Comment: It seems to be the middle part, right after d=n1**2, with the reshape and repeat operations that follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code, tracking the size of the results:

```
In [22]: n1 = 5
    ...: n2 = 800
    ...: n3 = 1000
    ...: 
    ...: a = np.random.rand(n1, n2, n3)
In [23]: a.shape
Out[23]: (5, 800, 1000)
In [24]: a_new = np.array([np.repeat(a[np.newaxis, ll, :, :], n1, axis=0) for ll in range(n1)])
    ...: 
In [25]: a_new.shape
Out[25]: (5, 5, 800, 1000)
In [26]: d = n1**2
    ...: a1 = np.reshape(a_new, (d, n2, n3))
    ...: a1 = np.repeat(a1[np.newaxis, :, :, :], n1, axis=0)
    ...: 
In [27]: a1.shape
Out[27]: (5, 25, 800, 1000)
In [28]: d2 = d * n1
    ...: a2 = np.reshape(a1, (d2, n2, n3))
    ...: a2 = np.reshape(a2, (d2 * n2, n3))
    ...: 
    ...: 
In [29]: a2.shape
Out[29]: (100000, 1000)
```

A minor point, but the double `reshape` in `a2` isn't necessary.  YOu can go directly to the last shape.  In any case, reshape is fast (unless it has to force a copy, as after a transpose).

Some times

```
In [34]: %timeit a_new = np.array([np.repeat(a[np.newaxis, ll, :, :], n1, axis=0) for ll in range(n1)])
263 ms ± 11.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [36]: a1  = np.reshape( a_new, ( d, n2, n3  ) )
In [37]: %timeit np.repeat( a_new[np.newaxis,:,:,:], n1, axis=0 )
912 ms ± 134 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

So yes, the repeat does take the most time.  But it's increasing the size of a large array 5x.  `repeat` is relatively fast - for something that makes a large array.

Your `a_new` list comprehension isn't necessary:

```
In [41]: np.repeat(a[:, None, :, :], n1, axis=1).shape
Out[41]: (5, 5, 800, 1000)
In [42]: np.allclose(np.repeat(a[:, None, :, :], n1, axis=1), a_new)
Out[42]: True
In [43]: %timeit np.repeat(a[:, None, :, :], n1, axis=1)
210 ms ± 23.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

The time savings are modest, since the `n1` loop is only 5x.

Note that the following `repeat` is takes about 5x.  `a_new` is 5x the size of `a`, and `a1` 25 times the size of `a`.

We could do it all in one line

```
In [44]: a4 = np.repeat(np.repeat(a[:,None,:,:], n1, axis=1)[None],n1, axis=0).reshape(-1,n3)
In [45]: a4.shape
Out[45]: (100000, 1000)
In [46]: np.allclose(a2, a4)
Out[46]: True
```

It doesn't change the time much.  Interestingly the [46] allclose takes the most noticeable time.

The double repeat can be written with `tile`:

```
a5 = np.tile(a[None,None,:,:],(5,5,1,1)).reshape(-1,n3)
```

It doesn't save time, because `tile` uses `repeat` repeatedly on each dimension.

Or even

```
a6 = np.repeat(a[None,:,:], n1*n1,axis=0).reshape(-1,n3)
```

I'm not going to time or test this since creating several arrays of this size was pushing my memory limits.